Outer measure from distance
Consider the function where $\alpha > 0$, and $X$ is a metric space. $B_a \subset P(X)$ is the system of sets with a diameter smaller than $a$. Define:
$$f(A) := \inf \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{diam}^\alpha (A_n) := \sum_n \nu(A_n) \mid A_n \in B_a, A \subset \bigcup_n A_n \right\}.$$
I need to show:

That $f$ is an outer measure.

I have checked the first two attributes, but I am unsure of my proof of the sigma-subadditivity.
Proof of sigma-subadditivity:
Let $S = \bigcup_i S_i$ be a set. For each set $S_i$, we find a cover such that:
$$S_i \subset \bigcup_n A_n^i.$$
Now, due to the definition of the infimum, we have:
$$f(S_i) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} \geq \sum_n \nu(A_n^i).$$
Summing over all $i$, we get:
\begin{equation} \label{1}
\sum_i f(S_i) + \epsilon \geq \sum_{n,i} \nu(A_n^i).
\end{equation}
And since:
$$f(S) := \inf \left\{ \sum_n \nu(A_n) \mid A_n \in B_a, S \subset \bigcup_n A_n \right\},$$
Thus the right-handside must be bigger than $f(S)$. We have thus:
$$ \sum_i f(S_i) +\epsilon \geq f(S), \forall \epsilon>0$$
At this point, i am not sure how to conclude the proof. If Epsilon is zero, it might not be correct anymore. Furthermore, i am not sure if  i deduced correctly, that the right handside is bigger than $f(S)$
The second part of this questions asks to display that if:
$dist(A,B)> 0 \Rightarrow g(A\cup B)=g(A)\cup g(B) $ whereas $g(A):= \sup_{a>0} f(A)$. The inequality to the left is given by the above-shown sub-additivity. The other direction illudes me.
